# Exclude client roles from access_token in keycloak

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token, roles

I've a keycloak with multiple clients and roles. so all the clients and roles would come in keycloak access_token when client is asssigned to user/group.

Now i have scenario where **I want to remove one client and their roles from keycloak access_token** other clients should come in access_token.

if anyone can help here would be much appreciated.

thankyou in advance!